# Returning values from a PHP script for an AJAX method: What am I doing wrong here?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

From everything I've read on the internet, the way of returning HTML, JSON, etc., from a PHP script is simply by `echo`ing it. I can't get it to work, however.

My JS is

```
        jQuery('#new-member').submit(
            function()
            {
                var formUrl = jQuery(this).attr('action');
                var formMethod = jQuery(this).attr('method');
                var postData = jQuery(this).serializeArray();
                console.log(postData); // test for now
                jQuery.ajax(
                    {
                        url: formUrl,
                        type: formMethod,
                        dataType: 'json',
                        data: postData,
                        success: function(retmsg)
                        {
                            alert(retmsg); // test for now
                        }, 
                        error: function()
                        {
                            alert("error"); // test for now
                        }
                    }
                );
                return false;
            }       
        );
```

and I've verified that it is correctly calling my PHP script, which as a test is simply

```
<?php
   echo "Yo, dawg.";
?>
```

but all that does is open `"Yo, dawg."` in a new page. The expected behavior is for it to `alert` that message on the same page I was on. What am I missing here?

Comment: Having the content opened in a new page means that the form has been submitted through the natural behavior. Try adding the event parameter here: `.submit(function(e)`, and adding `e.preventDefault();` before your `return` statement. If that does not work, make sure that your form has the right ID `new-member`. Oh, and open your JS console by hitting F12, to see if there are any errors, and see what goes on in the _Network_ tab.

Comment: If this code is attached to an `<input type="submit"...` you definitely need to do something to prevent the default action. Or, you could change the submit button to something that doesn't have a default submit action, like `<button type="button"...`

Comment: @blex I tried that; still doesn't work. I looked in the JS console and Network and nothing looks off.

Comment: You need more DEVELOPERS! DEVELOPER! DEVELOPERS!

Comment: @Don'tPanic Yep, that was my problem ....